# How to apply min heapify to a string array c#?

Tags: c#

I want to order a test file of string words, some with punctuation, from A-Z and the Z-A.
I have been able to implement max heapify for int, and double variables but get the error "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'" 
This is my current code:

```
private static void Min_Heapify(string[] Array, int ArraySize, int Index)
    {
        int Left = (Index + 1) * 2 - 1;
        int Right = (Index + 1) * 2;
        int largest = 0;
        if (Left < ArraySize&& Array[Left] < Array[Index])
        {
            largest = Left;
        }
        else
        {
            largest = Index;
        }
        if (Right < ArraySize&& Array[Right] < Array[largest])
        {
            largest = Right;
        }
        if (largest != Index)
        {
            string temp = Array[Index];
            Heap[Index] = Array[largest];
            Heap[largest] = temp;
            Min_Heapify(Array, ArraySize, largest);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string.Compare`: it will return `< 0` if first < second, `= 0` if first = second, `> 0` if first > second. So, for example:

```
if (Left < ArraySize && string.Compare(Array[Left], Array[Index]) < 0)
```

and

```
if (Right < ArraySize && string.Compare(Array[Right], Array[largest]) < 0)
```

Comment: Could also make the method generic with a constraint on `IComparable<T>`, rather than implementing versions for every type

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 That isn't the way it is normally done. You use a generic `T` parameter without constraints, an optional `Comparer<T>` or `Comparison<T>` parameter and if `null` you retrieve the Comparer<T>.Default or the `Comparator<T>.Default.Compare`. Note that if you want a high performance sort, eschewing generics and the use of `Comparer<>`/`Comparison<>`/`IComparable<>` can be faster (one less `virtual`/delegate method call)

Comment: Well, same sort of idea. The point I was trying to make was that it could be adapted a bit to not have to fully repeat the implementation per type.